# How to load a specific log4j.properties file if more than 1 exists in the classpath

Tags: java, log4j

Below is my scenario..

I am developing a new webapp which would be deployed on a weblogic server.
But there is already an existing webapp up and running on the same weblogic server.
Specific to this existing app, there is a log4j.properties file in an external location.

This location is added to the classpath in the weblogicStart.sh file.
My requirement is to add a new log4j.properties file and my new app should detect that than the old one.
So, are there are configurations that can be done so that my app picks up the new log4j file.

Answer (score 0):

with `PropertyConfigurator.configure().`

see [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add log4j.jar to you webapp WEB-INF/lib and log4j.properties to WEB-INF/. Make sure that Weblogic Server is configured for  `prefer-web-inf-classes` mode, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html. This ensures that your webabb loads and initializes its own version of log4j.